# Pandas: removing float values from output of a pivot_table used for counting

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following (toy) dataset:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'System_Key':['MER-002', 'MER-003', 'MER-004', 'MER-005', 'BAV-378', 'BAV-379', 'BAV-380', 'BAV-381', 'AUD-220', 'AUD-221', 'AUD-222', 'AUD-223'],
                   'Manufacturer':['Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'Mercedes', 'BMW', 'BMW', 'BMW', 'BMW', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi', 'Audi'],
                   'Region':['Americas', 'Europe', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Europe', 'Americas', 'Asia', 'Americas', 'Americas'],
                   'Department':[np.nan, 'Sales', np.nan, 'Operations', np.nan, np.nan, 'Accounting', np.nan, 'Finance', 'Finance', 'Finance', np.nan]
                  })

    System_Key  Manufacturer    Region       Department
0   MER-002     Mercedes        Americas     NaN
1   MER-003     Mercedes        Europe       Sales
2   MER-004     Mercedes        Americas     NaN
3   MER-005     Mercedes        Asia         Operations
4   BAV-378     BMW             Asia         NaN
5   BAV-379     BMW             Europe       NaN
6   BAV-380     BMW             Europe       Accounting
7   BAV-381     BMW             Europe       NaN
8   AUD-220     Audi            Americas     Finance
9   AUD-221     Audi            Asia         Finance
10  AUD-222     Audi            Americas     Finance
11  AUD-223     Audi            Americas     NaN
```

First, I remove the NaN values in the data frame:

```
df = df.fillna('')
```

Then, I pivot the data frame as follows:

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Manufacturer', columns='Region', values='System_Key', aggfunc='size').applymap(str)
```

**Notice that I'm passing `aggfunc='size'` for counting.**

This results in the following pivot table:

```
Region           Americas   Asia    Europe
Manufacturer            
Audi             3.0        1.0     NaN
BMW              NaN        1.0     3.0
Mercedes         2.0        1.0     1.0
```

How would I convert the float values in this pivot table to integers?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The only reason you get floats when aggregating integers is because some missing `size()` values are NaN. Do you want to keep the NaN's or impute them to zeros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The only reason you get floats when aggregating integers is because some missing size() values are NaN. So use `fill_value=0` to impute them to zeros**. Avoid getting the NaNs in the first place:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Manufacturer', columns='Region', values='System_Key', aggfunc='size', fill_value=0)

Region        Americas  Asia  Europe
Manufacturer                        
Audi                 3     1       0
BMW                  0     1       3
Mercedes             2     1       1
```

Notes:

- This is much better than kludging the dtype after.
- You also don't need the `df.fillna('')`, and filling NaN with string '' on an integer(/float) column is a bad idea
- Note you don't need to do `pd.pivot_table(df, ...)`, just call `df.pivot_table(...)` directly since it's a method of dataframe.

Answer (score 5):

Try `fill_value`

```
pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, index='Manufacturer', columns='Region', values='System_Key', aggfunc='size',fill_value=-1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you have `NaN` in your data, pandas would automatically downcast to float. You can either use `Int64` (available from Pandas 0.24+) datatype:

```
pivot = (pd.pivot_table(df, index='Manufacturer', columns='Region', 
                        values='System_Key', aggfunc='size')
           .astype('Int64')
        )
```

Output:

```
Region        Americas  Asia  Europe
Manufacturer                        
Audi                 3     1    <NA>
BMW               <NA>     1       3
Mercedes             2     1       1
```

or fill `NaN` with, say, `-1` in `pivot_table`:

```
pivot = (pd.pivot_table(df, index='Manufacturer', columns='Region', 
                        values='System_Key', aggfunc='size',
                        fill_value=-1)   # <--- here
        )
```

Output:

```
Region        Americas  Asia  Europe
Manufacturer                        
Audi                 3     1      -1
BMW                 -1     1       3
Mercedes             2     1       1
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Int64 datatype](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) which allows for intgeger NaNs. The [convert_dtypes()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.convert_dtypes.html) function would be handy here.

```
pivot.convert_dtypes()
              Americas  Asia  Europe
Manufacturer                        
Audi                 3     1    <NA>
BMW               <NA>     1       3
Mercedes             2     1       1
```

Also...

1. I'd probably do `df.fillna('', inplace=True)` instead of `df = df.fillna('')` to minimize data copies
2. I assume you meant to ditch the `.applymap(str)` bit at the end of your call to `pivot_table()`.